# Getting Mismatch sender Id in android Fcm Notifications in server side

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, sender-id

I generated fcm keys for android notifications such as **Server Legacy Key** and **sender Id**. I Got my refresh token as

```
 String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

But getting **mismatch SenderId**. But I checked all those credentials. Provided credentials all are correct. Don't Know how to overcome this issue. But with my another apps credentials getting success response. please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you give Server key to backend guy?